# dynamically added link are not triggering in php

Tags: php

I have added images and the corresponding links to the database and viewed on index page, problem is when i click the images it goes to the present page, it does not open corresponding links related to images. But same is working fine in marquee.

code for adding images and links is

```
<?php
    include_once("../init.php");
    validation_check($_SESSION['UID'], SITE_HOME_ADMIN);

    $msg='';
    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        $upDir ='../'.VIDEO;
        $videourl = $_POST['videourl'];

        $insertSql =("INSERT INTO videonews (videourl) 
        VALUES ('$videourl')");
        $insertSql="INSERT INTO ".VIDEONEWS." SET 
            `adv_url`           = '".realStrip($_POST['adv_url'])."'";
        $query = mysql_query($insertSql);
        $adv_id = mysql_insert_id();
        $adv = '';
        if($_FILES["adv"]['name']!= ''){
            $fileData  = pathinfo(basename($_FILES["adv"]["name"]));
            $adv = $adv_id . '_adv.' . $fileData ['extension']; 
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["adv"]["tmp_name"], $upDir . $adv);
        }
        $upSql="UPDATE ".VIDEONEWS." SET `adv` = '".$adv."' WHERE id = '$adv_id'";
        $query = mysql_query($upSql);

        $msg = '<h3>Record Saved</h3>'; 
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Video News</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headerstyle.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">


</script>
</head>
<body>
07/25/2014
<div class="fixx">
  <?php include('header.php');?>
</div>
<div class="tabl">
  <table width="700" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td><form action="news1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <table width="900" border="1" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ADD Files To Video News  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;| &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="news1_list.php"> EDIT</a> </h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><?php echo $msg;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td><input type="file" name="adv" id="adv" /><input type="text" placeholder="URL" name="adv_url" id="adv_url" size="50" /></td></tr>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Video Link <input type="text" name="videourl" id="videourl" size="100" /></td></tr>
             <tr> <td><input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Submit" /></td></tr>

          </table>
        </form></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Retrieving file code is

```
<?php 

validation_check($_SESSION['UID'], SITE_HOME_ADMIN);
    $msg='';
    $adDir ='./'.VIDEO;

$qr = mysql_query("select * from ".VIDEONEWS) or die('Error in connection');
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($qr))
{
    $adv = '';
    if($rs['adv']!='') {
        $adv = '<a href="'.$adv['adv_url'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$adDir.$rs['adv'].'" style="width:250px; height:150px" >&nbsp; </a>';
    }
    $image = $adv;
 $msg .='<tr>
    <tr>'.$image.'</tr>


  </tr>';
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Videonews Lists</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headerstyle.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="tabl">
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" class="main">

    <td>
<table width="95%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="10">


 <?php echo $msg;?>
</table>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Retrieving file is included in index.php to show all images in a frame.

Marquee code in index page which is working fine is

```
<div class="ads-242x90 right">
                <a href="#"> <strong>VIDEO NEWS</strong></a>

                <marquee direction="up" scrollamount="2"  onmouseover="this.stop();"   onmouseout="this.start();">
            <div align="left" >
            <span style="text-transform:uppercase;">  
              <?
                $qryAdv = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".VIDEONEWS." WHERE 1");
                if(mysql_num_rows($qryAdv) > 0)
                {
                    while($adv = mysql_fetch_assoc($qryAdv))
                    {
              ?>
             <a href= "#" onClick="window.open('<?=$adv['adv_url']?>', '_blank')"><img src="<?=VIDEO.$adv['adv']?>" width="98%"  height="90" alt=""></a> <br /> 
              <?
                    }
                } else { echo 'NO ADDS FOUND!!!'; }
              ?>
              </marquee>
```

Comment: Show us dump of first result row: `var_dump($rs)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you should do is to protect yourself from SQL injection, read about it.

I think your problem lies here:

```
$adv = '';  ///you set $adv equal to empty string
if($rs['adv']!='') {      //VVVV here you try to use your empty string
    $adv = '<a href="'.$adv['adv_url'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$adDir.$rs['adv'].'" style="width:250px; height:150px" >&nbsp; </a>';
}
```

I believe it should be

```
                     //VVVVVV
$adv = '<a href="'.$rs['adv_url'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$adDir.$rs['adv'].'" style="width:250px; height:150px" >&nbsp; </a>';
```

Comment: `$adv` and `$rs['adv']` are different.